# How to test a dynamic date field in cypress with mock data?

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I want to test a popup component if the date in mockData exceeds 20 minutes from now, I will open it. But the problem is if I give static a date field in the fixture file, it will not test it in the pipeline after days. **isExceedTime** function return a boolean value if the date exceeds 20 minutes from now.

a.json

```
{date: "2023-03-06T17:16:52.655564"}
```

a.test.js

```
it('should show dialog', () => {
   cy.intercept(
    {
      method: 'GET',
      pathname: '/api/a',
      https: true,
    },
    {
      fixture: `a.json`,
    },
  ).as("mockData")

  cy.visit("/")

  cy.wait("@mockData")
   
  cy.findByRole('dialog').should('exist');
});
```

a.js

```
import React from "react";
import isExceedTime from "isExceedTime"

export const Popup = ({ date }) => {

const [open, setIsOpen] = React.useState(isExceedTime(date))

if(!open){
 return null;
}

return (
    <div className="popup-container" role="dialog">
      <div className="popup-body">
        <h1>adasdasdasdasd</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
);
};
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you couldn't set the static value to being an arbitrarily high future data? Something like 10+ years in the future?

Answer (score 4):

The official way is to set the clock for the test with [cy.clock()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock#Now)

```js
const now = new Date(2023, 2, 5) // month is 0-indexed

cy.clock(now)   // -1 day behind your fixture value

cy.intercept(
  { method: 'GET', pathname: '/api/a', https: true },
  { fixture: `a.json` }
).as("mockData")

cy.visit("/")

cy.wait("@mockData")
   
cy.findByRole('dialog').should('exist')
```

This fixes the real-world date for your app to be the same each time you run.

Arguably better than dynamically changing the date, since you don't get caught by edge cases like leap years (if that applies in your scenario).

You can also *specifically* test edge cases like leap years using this method, which is not possible when applying the date dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that by refactoring your interceptor part to:

```
cy.intercept('GET', '/api/a', { date: new Date(Date.now() + 60_000 * 20).toISOString() })
```

You can move then move this logic into a function accepting the multiplier to test different scenarios